# SQL Embedded Case

Tags: sql, case

I am new to Sql. The logic of those tables without IF condition always annoys me. I have a table (MyTable) like this:

```
ID ProjectID ClassType  ClassYear Amount
1   1   A   2014    0.00
2   1   A   2014    0.00
3   1   B   2014    300.00
5   1   B   2013    100.00
6   1   C   2015    200.00
7   1   A   2013    0.00
8   1   B   2015    200.00
9   1   B   2014    500.00
11  1   B   2015    230.00
....
```

My original code as following works fine:

```
Some code 
from 
(
    Select projectID, sum(currentyear) as CurrentYear, sum(prioryear) as PriorYear, sum(postyear) as PostYear
    from 
        (select ProjectID, 
            case when Classyear = 2014 then Amount else 0 end as currentyear,
            case when ClassYear <2014 then Amount else 0 end as prioryear,
            case when ClassYear > 2014 then Amount else 0 end as postyear 
            from MyTable
            where classtype = 'A'
         ) as subtable
    group by subtable.ProjectID
)
```

Right now I want to add more option for the classtype in the above and can not figure out how. The logic should be:

if total amount  from classtype A in a project is 0 (in other word, those three numbers are all 0)then the where condition should change to classtype = 'B'. If classtype B are still all 0 then use the classtype C. (It will be OK if C are still 0).

Where should I put the new case condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can get total using `GROUP BY` for each class type and then filter appropriate value.

```
 SELECT * 
FROM
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by projectId order by classType) as seq FROM
(
    Select projectID, classType, sum(Amount) as Total, 
           sum(case when Classyear = 2014 then Amount else 0 end) as CurrentYear, 
           sum(case when ClassYear <2014 then Amount else 0 end) as PriorYear, 
           sum( case when ClassYear > 2014 then Amount else 0 end) as PostYear

    from 
    myTable
    group by ProjectID, classType
) T
Where (T.Total >0 and classType <> 'C') or classType ='C' 
) C
where seq =1
```

Comment: You are genius. Looks like I have to change something from language coding to SQL. They are completely in different way. Thanks a lot, Radar.

Comment: Ops, actually it works fine only for one projectID, I want to collect for all projectID. Not work for this situation.

Comment: @user3191850, can you explain it bit more?

Comment: ProjectID could be 2, 3, .. I need to list all of the data for each projectID. Above code only listed the first project.

Comment: @user3191850, updated thee answer, you can do it with CTE also with out subquery to make it more readable, as u have other code using it, i kept it in subqueries

Comment: Yes. this time it worked perfectly. Sorry for late, working on others. I really need to learn more on those SQL. So complicated. Most of time, I still like to extract data and process them in C# although it may be slower than on SQL level directly. Thanks a lot!